# Easy to use XML parser

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I have XML as follows:

```
<Game>
   <ID>8585></ID>
   <ApplicationPath>F:\Games\gamename.zip</ApplicationPath>
   <DateAdded>2021-03-20T18:03:57.1370703-04:00</DateAdded>
   <DateModified>2021-04-16T22:00:45.3921555-04:00</DateModified>
   <Category>Platformer</Category>
   <Developer />
   <Notes />
</Game>
<Game>
   <ID>8855></ID>
   <ApplicationPath>F:\Games\hat\gamename.zip</ApplicationPath>
   <DateAdded>2021-03-20T18:03:57.1370703-04:00</DateAdded>
   <DateModified>2021-04-16T22:00:45.3921555-04:00</DateModified>
   <Category>Platformer</Category>
   <Developer />
   <Notes />
</Game>
```

I am looking for a very easy and simple way to parse through this XML, which contains thousands of lines such that I can search through it to find every instance of games where ApplicationPath contains "hat" and replace the associated Category of that game with "puzzle".

If this can be accomplished in Notepad++, how? If not, I'm open to any recommendations.

Thank you

Comment: I want to find all ApplicationPaths whose value contains "hat" and replace the Category with "Puzzle"

Comment: Like I said, there are thousands of lines. I added an extra set the very second before you replied to help clear that up.

Comment: Recommendations for tools/libraries/software or other off-site resources are [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow. A better place to ask would be the [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: I'm not asking for recommendations for tools or resources exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

With [`xmlstarlet`](https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php):

```
xmlstarlet edit -u '//Game[contains(ApplicationPath, "hat")]/Category' \
  -v puzzle file.xml
```

Not sure the quotes are working the same as Linux. If you have an error, invert the quotes:

- single quotes -> double quotes
- double quotes -> single quotes

Add `-L` to edit the file on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

With Saxon's [Gizmo](https://www.saxonica.com/documentation11/index.html#!gizmo):

```
java net.sf.saxon.Gizmo -s:input.xml
/>update //Game[contains(ApplicationPath, 'hat')]/Category with "puzzle"
/>save output.xml
/>quit
```